# Javascript/Jquery/Gantt Highchart : On clicking over a task progress pop-up should get open

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

[image]

Refer the above Gantt Chart.

I am loading this Gantt Chart in `<div id="containter">`.  I need a **jQuery Show Bootstrap Modal Popup on clicking only a Task Progress** not by clicking a *containter*.

I tried this code,

```
  $(function () {
            $("#container").click(function () {
                $('#demoModal').modal('show');
            });
        });
```

```
   <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="demoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                         <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Task Progress Indicator</h4>
                   </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">Task Progress Indicator</div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                   <%-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>--%>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Bootstrap modal pop-up window get open when clicking anywhere over the chart. I want **pop-up window** should get open only on clicking over the task progress not on the indicator.

Please give me a solution what to do.

Comment: what does your gantt chart container div looks like? Maybe try changing the id on your click trigger to the id of the progress bar not the container id...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add following settings in your gantt chart config

```
plotOptions: {
   series: {
      point: {
         events: {
           click: (event) => {
              console.log(event);
              $('#demoModal').modal('show');
           }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It's working. But one more thing once pop-up gets opened. Details should loaded. I am using    url: "Performance.aspx/getLineChartData2" in ajax calling C# method. Where can i place this code ?

Comment: I can't answer that. I don't have any knowledge of C#, I do only know javascript and js frameworks. I can only tell you that you will get all data related to clicked series in `event` argument, using which you can get to know which series is clicked.